# C# WCF Can't access service with external adress

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

Having some issues with my WCF service.
I'm currently working on a Client/Server chat application and can't access the server remotely.
Locally works just fine, but the moment I try to connect to it remotely (from a different computer in a different network) I get

> TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond IP-Adress:3100

If I try to connect to myself through my external IP-Adress I get

> TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it

My port (3100) is open in my router, firewall is disabled and portsharing enabled.

**Server:**

```
 svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceAssembly.ServiceImplementation));

        NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();

        tcpBinding.MaxConnections = 100;
        tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = (int)4096;
        tcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
        tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = (int)4096;
        tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
        tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel =
           System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
        tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
           TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
        svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(ServiceAssembly.IChat),
            tcpBinding,
            "net.tcp://localhost:3100/MyService");

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());


        Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
        try
        {
            svh.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
```

**Client:**

```
public string m_ipAdress = "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
    string m_port = "3100";
    DuplexChannelFactory<IChat> scf;
    IChat s;

    private void login_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Callback callback = new Callback();
        InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);
        NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();

        tcpBinding.MaxConnections = 100;
        tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = (int)4096;
        tcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
        tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = (int)4096;
        tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
        tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel =
           System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
        tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
           TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

        scf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChat>(context, tcpBinding,
                    "net.tcp://" + m_ipAdress + ":" + m_port + "/MyService");
        s = scf.CreateChannel();
        try
        {
            s.Connect();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

On s.Connect() is where my program hangs and I get the TCP error. It's the first call to the server.

I have searched and searched for answers, but nothing has been helpful...
Hosting the server on Windows 10.
If there's anything I need to add, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the server end doesnt have a firewall? Can you connect to the port when its on the server, eg connect to itself

Comment: @BugFinder the firewall is completely disabled. My router has it's firewall disabled aswell. No anti-virus firewall is running. When I connect to the port locally (using localhost:3100) everything's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what's causing this issue.
I've been using localhost as my server endpoint adress. Changed it to my networkadapters local IP(192.168.1.150) and everything works.